# How should template names be set dynamically using class based views?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I've searched through the ref and topics of the class based views Django documentation(Django 1.4) but I haven't found any mentioning of this. **How do I set template names dynamically using class based views?** I'm looking for the **class-based equivalent of the following setup**:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from mysite.views import dynamic

urlspatterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'^dynamic/(?P<template>\w+)/$', dynamic),)
)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def dynamic(request, template):
    template_name = "%s.html" % template 
    return render_to_response(template_name, {})
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to define get_template_names that returns list of template_names.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class DynamicTemplateView(TemplateView):

    def get_template_names(self):
        return ['%s.html' % self.kwargs['template']]
```

Comment: You mean `class DynamixTemplateView(TemplateView)` instead of `def DynamixTemplateView(TemplateView)` I presume.

Comment: Btw, I had to do `return ['%s.html' % self.kwargs['template']] ` instead of `return [self.kwargs['template']]` in order to avoid typing the html suffix in the url. Class based views look rlly ugly imo.

Comment: Yes, template_name should have the .html extension in it.