# passing template name into DJango view for rendering

Tags: django, templates

I am working with a `DJango View`. It is being implemented as a `function-based view`. What I would like to do is to pass in a template into the function for rendering into an HTML document.

In the example below, instead of hardcoding  **'storeowner/mstrstorehead_form.html'**, I would like to pass in a template name for use.

How can this be done? I saw the information here:

[How should template names be set dynamically using class based views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448150/how-should-template-names-be-set-dynamically-using-class-based-views)

but it deals more with Class-Based-Views

TIA

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def edit_store_data(request):
    success = False
    message = 'No changes to report'
    message_color = 'green'

    username = request.user.username
    local_email = request.user.email
    local_pass = request.user.password

    [... snip ... ]

    return render(request, 'storeowner/mstrstorehead_form.html',
                          {'form': master_store_head_form, 'success': `success, 'message': message, 'message_color': message_color})`
```

## Update

The way this is working is that a user "signs up" with the EMail address and password. A "logon link" is sent to the user as part of a "verification email".

What happens when clicking on the login link depends on whether or not additional (needed) information needed is already in the DB.

If the information is not in the DB: When clicking on the link, the user will transferred to a page to enter it into the system (represented by this form - first name, last name, etc.). After the basic info is saved, the user will be transferred to a "home page"

If the information is in the DB: the user will be automatically transferred to the home page.

Either way, when the user is logged in, he/she will have an opportunity to change the data (once logged in) - by clicking on one of the menu items (ex: Profile)

So, this cpde can be called from 2 places

- => once to "initialize" the DB with data (before logging into the home page)
- => another time to modify the data - after logging into the homepage (ex: if the person gets married and has to change the last name in
  the DB)

The only thing that would change (between the 2 places) is the template being used (hence my desire to pass it in). It is similar to the problem mentioned above (except it is referring to cross-based-views)

Comment: Where do you want to pass the name from? In other words, where does the logic sit that decides which name to use?

Comment: @Dewald Abrie - thanks for the response!  Pls see update

Comment: Your update talks about a condition; there's nothing here that requires "passing in" a template. A simple if statement would go the job, surely?

Comment: If the link in the email takes you to the view you listed, then he will be denied (assuming you use django's authentication) because the user hasn't logged yet and you're using the @login_required decorator on the view.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6064820/dewald-abrie - thanks for the response. Basically, the idea is that the person would log in on the log in page. IF the needed data been filled out, he will be directed home. If not, he will be directed a another page that allows him to fill in just the BASIC data - enough so that the home page will work OK. I eventually switched to using class-based-views

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you're after is a [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect).

First you can check the HTTP GET data supplied in the url and do some DB lookups, then - depending on your requirements - you can redirect to either the homepage or another page with a webform for more info.

Perhaps something like the following:

```
def link_process(request):
    # get some GET params encoded in URL like 
    # www.mydomain.com/handle_login_link?username=john
    username = request.GET['username']
    # do related db lookups:
    ...

    #conditional redirect
    if need_more_data:
        return redirect('some-view-name', form=MoreDataForm)
    else:
        return redirect('homepage')
```